# How can i resolve this point (a,b) combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, education, multisets

In a given programming language, an identifier is a sequence of a certain number of characters in which the first character must be a letter of the English alphabet and the rest can be a letter or a digit.
a How many identifiers are there of length 5?

b. In particular, some implementations of Pascal and identifier is a sequence of 1 to 8
characters with the above description. How many Pascal identifiers are there?
I tried to do this: there are five spaces, the first is 26 and the others could be 36 because 10+26, but I don’t know how to resolve this.
I don’t know how to resolve b.

Answer (score 1):

> first character must be a letter of the English alphabet and the rest can be a letter or a digit. How many identifiers are there of length 5?

Well, there are $26$ possibilities for the first character, and $26+10$ possibilities for the remaining 4 spots.
That's: $(26)(36^4)=43,670,016$ possible combinations

As for $n$ characters, there will be $(26)(36^{n-1})$ possible combinations